# Vue. Рендер html с bind's в template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, компоненты, render

Необходима помощь. Есть Vue компонент. В параметры передается html-строка. Необходимо вывести html в template этого компонента. Да, я знаю про v-html. Но есть одно но. В этом самом html есть двойные фигурные скобки, в которые передается шаблон. Т.е.

```html
<div>
  <div>
    {{user.Name}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{user.LastName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

И проблема в том, что в template это конструкция выводится как есть, не подставляя данные из объекта user.
Вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы в template попадал обработанный html?

P.S. Если кто не до конца понял, скину примерный код.

```js
Vue.component("my-component",{
  props: ['templateHtml','user'],
  template: '<div>\
              <p>First html</p>\
              <span v-html="templateHtml.First"></span>\
              <p>Second html</p>\
              <span v-html="templateHtml.Second"></span>\
             </div>'
});

//templateHtml: {
//  First: '<div>{{user.FirstName}}</div>,
//  Second: '<div>{{user.LastName}}</div>,
//}
```

```html
<my-component template-html="templateHtml" current-user="user"></my-component>
```

P.S.2. Код скинул для примера. На деле компонент больше и сложнее, но пример перекрестно описывает мою проблему.

Comment: Возможно тут поможет использование [слотов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот есть пакет: [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template)
Кажется именно ваш случай.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/258988)

Comment: @Air, слишком много тут указывать главного. А ссылка эта никуда не денется 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант не будет работать, при выводе через v-html биндинги не работают.

Comment: Тогда придется парсить как обычную строку?

Comment: Можно передавать только данные, а эти данные уже будут подставляться в компонент.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне необходимо, чтобы данные вставлялись не в компонент, а в html, который я передаю. А вот этот html уже вставлять в компонент

Comment: Я вас понял. Это просто один из вариантов решения - взять ту верстку что вы передаете, сделать компонент на ее основе, и в этот компонент уже передавать данные.